# Stopping ntp - time is still jumping back in Debian

Tags: debian, time, ntp

I do something like:
service ntp stop
503  date +%T -s "15:10:00"

But after a while it jums forward to the correct time (If I put it forward in time, it seems to be working).

This is a VMWare Linux Debian VM.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to set the time to something that's wrong? And is the problem its getting corrected? (Its OK if that's the use case, you just need to state it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the VMWare Linux Tools installed on the Guest, then it will sync the VM's time to the Host's time by default (I believe it's on by default), regardless of NTP settings.

Edit the .vmx file of your VM and add/change `tools.synctime = "FALSE"`.

I believe you can also toggle it via GUI if you have the vmware-toolbox X application installed.

More info: [Here](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf) and [Here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427)

Comment: .vmx didn't work, but the vmware-toolbox did.